# A condition on triples of elements in a random collection of ordered pairs.

Tags: probability

This question arose out of some research in group theory on random group presentations. The actual question is  more complicated, but I think the following captures the essence of it. It is similar to the birthday coincidence problem, but involves a condition on triples rather than pairs. I have no idea how difficult it is.

We have a set $A$ of size $n$ and we choose a set $P$ of $r$ random ordered pairs of distinct elements of $A$. I would like to estimate the probability, as a function of $n$ and $r$,  that there exist three elements of $P$ of the form $(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)$ for some $a,b,c \in A$.

Comment: Have you resolved this question now?

Comment: Yes it was effectively resolved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257391/). It was easy for the mathoverflow gang!